# how to define 'owner" for a process instance in activiti

Tags: activiti, owner

I am creating a very simple workflow:

```
<process id="test" name="test" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="start" name="start" activiti:initiator="initiator"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="user" name="ownertask" activiti:candidateGroups="management"></userTask>
    <endEvent id="end" name="end"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" name="flow1" sourceRef="start" targetRef="user"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" name="flow2" sourceRef="user" targetRef="end"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
```

i want to define "owner" for this process instance. How i can achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your case, the 'initiator' process instance variable already has the userId of the user that started the process, so you can use it to represent the "owner" of this instance.

You´re free to change the variable name by changing the value of the activiti:initiator property to whatever  name you like.

Answer (score 1):

Set **owner** as process instance variable:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("Owner", "John");    
runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("test", parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I don't want to set owner programmatically . I want to set owner in activiti-explorer web. How i can achieve this in activiti explorer web.

Comment: You can change definition and use ScriptTask
<scriptTask id="theScriptTask" name="Execute script" scriptFormat="groovy">
    <script>
        execution.setVariable("owner", "John")
    </script>
</scriptTask>